# Why Netlify shows me Error 254 while deploying on Netlify?

Tags: deployment, netlify

I'm a beginner programmer who just wants to upload my website written in javascript (react.js).
Unfortunately, I get errors during deployment.

I have read dozens of topics, watched many videos on YouTube, but I seriously don't know what is the cause. Is anyone able to help me?

Below is the code I get on Netlify:

```
7:22:53 PM: "build.command" failed                                        
7:22:53 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:22:53 PM: ​
7:22:53 PM:   Error message
7:22:53 PM:   Command failed with exit code 254: CI= npm run build
7:22:53 PM: ​
7:22:53 PM:   Error location
7:22:53 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
7:22:53 PM:   CI= npm run build
7:22:53 PM: ​
7:22:53 PM:   Resolved config
7:22:53 PM:   build:
7:22:53 PM:     command: CI= npm run build
7:22:53 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
7:22:53 PM:     environment:
7:22:53 PM:       - CI
7:22:53 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo
7:22:53 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
7:22:54 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
7:22:54 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
7:22:54 PM: Finished processing build request in 17.763s
7:22:54 PM: Failed during stage "building site": Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
```

The application works locally on my computer without any problem

I read forums and tried various solutions, but nothing helped.